# How many users can accept mosquitto user's list?

Tags: mosquitto, broker

I'm using the mosquitto service

I add the user to the users list in the file to authentication users when user subscribe to broker

Now if the number of users in this file is more than 100,000

Will it bring a heavy burden to the mosquitto?

My users may be more than a million user

Also i try to restrict users to self topic so i have to add topic name and username to ACL

So acl file is heavy

How do i manager all users authentication and acl without any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that many users a flat file is a REALLY bad idea, even if the data is converted into a easily searched data structure it will be a real problem to find users in the files to edit/remove.

This is exactly what the authentication plugin interface is for.

You can write your own using the API or JPMens has written a [plugin](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) that lets you keep the Username/Password and ACL in a selection of different databases (e.g. MySQL, Postgress, MongoDB, Redis...) .

Comment: Thank you it is best solution

Comment: About restrict topic,do you have idea? about restrict user for only one topic

Comment: You can store the ACL in the database as well